# How to prevent downloading unnecessary pages in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a problem in `nextJS`. I entered my website url and i went to my main page of website. I opened chrome devtools and i went to network tab. I saw that other pages had been downloaded! But i was in main page and i didnt go to any other page. Whats the problem here? How can i prevent something like this? Because it makes big problems in large apps! So my question is how can i prevent downloading unnecessary pages in `nextJS`? for example in plain `react` we could use `React.lazy` to download some components when we need them. we could use this method to prevent downloading unnecessary pages and components. like this exmple:

```
//App.js
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
const SupportPage = React.lazy(() => import("./Components/SupportPage"));

const App = () => {

   return (
     <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<p>loading the page...</p>}>
           <Routes>
              <Route path="/support" element={<SupportPage />} />
           </Routes>
        </Suspense>
     </div>
   )

}
```

but here, how can we do something like this? i have no idea about it. Thank you for helping.

Comment: how about this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388593/why-nextjs-loads-all-pages-at-first-load-when-i-build

Comment: thank you! it helped me. i googled a lot but i couldnt find something like this.